# g++ compiler with/without -O2

Tags: c++, compiler-optimization, g++4.8

I have the following source compiled by g++ 4.8.2 :

```
g++ --std=c++11 testx.cpp -pthread  -lrt  -O2 -o testx.exe
g++ --std=c++11 testx.cpp -pthread  -lrt  -o testy.exe
```

layout.h :

```
#pragma once
typedef struct DBInfo_
{
    volatile int seqno ;
    char groupname[32] ;
    char action[32] ;
    int booklayer ;
} DBInfo ;
#define DBARRAYSIZE 100
static DBInfo  *conf;
#define STATE_FILE "/strategy2/test.shared"
```

testx.cpp :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/file.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include "layout.h"

int g_DBSharedMemIdx = 0 ;
volatile int iGlbErrorSeqLock = 0 ;

void create_shmem(void)
{
    int shm_fd;
    if((shm_fd = shm_open(STATE_FILE, (O_CREAT | O_EXCL | O_RDWR),
                       (S_IREAD | S_IWRITE))) > 0 ) {
        printf("O_CREAT | O_EXCL | O_RDWR \n"); /* We are the first instance */
    }
    else if((shm_fd = shm_open(STATE_FILE, (O_CREAT | O_RDWR),
                        (S_IREAD | S_IWRITE))) < 0)
    {
        printf("Could not create shm object. \n");
        exit( 0 ) ;
    }
    int iTotalByte = sizeof(DBInfo)*DBARRAYSIZE ;
    ftruncate(shm_fd, iTotalByte );
    conf =  (DBInfo*) mmap(0, iTotalByte , (PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE), MAP_SHARED, shm_fd, 0) ;
    if(conf  == MAP_FAILED)
    {
        printf(" mmap error ....\n")  ;
        exit( 0 ) ;
    }
    g_DBSharedMemIdx = 0 ;
    (conf+g_DBSharedMemIdx)->seqno = 0 ;
    strcpy( (conf+g_DBSharedMemIdx)->groupname,"" ) ;
    strcpy( (conf+g_DBSharedMemIdx)->action,"" ) ;
    (conf+g_DBSharedMemIdx)->booklayer = 0 ;    
}//create_shmem

int getDBInfo(DBInfo& pDBInfo)
{
    if( pDBInfo.seqno == (conf+g_DBSharedMemIdx)->seqno)
        return 0 ;
    volatile int ilocalseqno1 = 0 , ilocalseqno2 = 0 ;
    volatile int icnt=0;
    while( 1 ){
        icnt++ ;
        if( icnt >= 10000 ){
            iGlbErrorSeqLock = 1 ;
            break ;
        }
        ilocalseqno1 = (conf+g_DBSharedMemIdx)->seqno ;
        if( ilocalseqno1 % 2 ){
            printf("***************************************************************************** \n");
            continue;
        }
        strcpy( pDBInfo.action,(conf+g_DBSharedMemIdx)->action ) ;
        pDBInfo.booklayer = (conf+g_DBSharedMemIdx)->booklayer ;

        ilocalseqno2 = (conf+g_DBSharedMemIdx)->seqno ;
        if( ilocalseqno1 != ilocalseqno2 ){
            printf("***************************************************************************** \n");
            continue;
        }
        pDBInfo.seqno = ilocalseqno2 ;
        break ;
    } //while
    if( iGlbErrorSeqLock == 1 )
        return -1 ;
    return 1 ;
}//getDBInfo


void *ThreadONE(void *param)
{
    printf("TestThread...(%p)\n",param) ;
    pthread_detach(pthread_self());
    while( 1 ){
        (conf+g_DBSharedMemIdx)->seqno++ ;
        strcpy( (conf+g_DBSharedMemIdx)->groupname,"group1" ) ;
        strcpy( (conf+g_DBSharedMemIdx)->action,"RUN" ) ;
        (conf+g_DBSharedMemIdx)->booklayer = 3 ;
        if( (conf+g_DBSharedMemIdx)->seqno % 2 == 1 )
            (conf+g_DBSharedMemIdx)->seqno++ ;
        usleep( 1 ) ;
    }//while 
}//ThreadONE

void *ThreadTWO(void *param)
{
    DBInfo pDBInfo ;
    printf("TestThread...(%p)\n",param) ;
    pthread_detach(pthread_self());
    int icnt = 0 ;
    while( 1 ){
        int iret = getDBInfo(pDBInfo);
        if( iret < 0 ){
            printf("iGlbErrorSeqLock happened \n") ;
            assert( iGlbErrorSeqLock == 100 );
        }else if(iret == 1){
            icnt++ ;
            //printf("icnt=(%d)\n",icnt);
        }
        usleep( 1 ) ;
    }//while 
}//ThreadTWO

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    create_shmem();

    sleep( 1 ) ;
    pthread_t tid ;
    pthread_create(&tid , NULL, ThreadONE, (void*)(long)3);
    pthread_create(&tid , NULL, ThreadTWO, (void*)(long)3);
    while( 1 )
        sleep( 5 ) ;
} //main
```

testy.exe(compiled without -O2) run will see "**************" 2 times per second ,

testx.exe(compiled with -O2) run will see "***********" not quite easy .

I have this test because in my original source , sometimes call function 
like getDBInfo will be trapped in endless loop if compiled with -O2, 
and it will be fine without -O2  , so I am curious what compiler do in 
getDBInfo function and what should I do according to it .

Comment: Both threads access the same structure simultaneously, one thread reading and one thread both reading from and writing to the structure. What do you think happens the reader thread tries to read the data while the other thread writes the data? If you want two threads to access the same data you need some kind of protection. This is what mutexes and semaphores are for.

Comment: I think one thread is reading and one thread is writing in this case ,and I run this application in intel cpu , sequential lock should work .